# Creating A Script For Dropping and Creating Views of a Database With Dependency Order, Programatically

Tags: sql, sql-server, dependencies, view

I just see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541086/script-all-views-functions-proceudres-in-a-sql-server-database-in-dependency-ord).
it's very similar to my question.
but i don't want to use any third party for creating the script.
i want to create the script of dropping and creating the views of a database in dependency order and programmatically.
how i can do such a thing ?

Comment: first, be very precise when you define dependency order of views - then query the data dictionary for those rules, then produce a script from the language of your choice.  then post what you have tried and what does not work.

Comment: thanks, i just want to do what you say, can you explain it more, i just tried ssms, scriptio and other Microsoft tool that is like the ssms generate script and i dont remember the name. can you or someone  else describe what you say in detail, thanks.

Comment: i found a way like this to create the commands, but it's without Dependency :

Comment: SELECT 'DROP VIEW ' + v.name As DropCmd, RTRIM(ISNULL(smv.definition, ssmv.definition) ) AS CreateCmd
FROM sys AS v
     LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.sql_modules AS smv ON smv.object_id = v.object_id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.system_sql_modules AS ssmv ON ssmv.object_id = v.object_id
WHERE v.type = 'V' AND SCHEMA_NAME(v.schema_id) = N'dbo'
ORDER BY v.name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I Found My Answer to be like this,
But Remember that this is just for views that has one nesting level. not more ! :

```
SELECT MIN(Row) AS Row, CreateCmd FROM ( 
SELECT Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY S.Row) As Row, S.CreateCmd FROM ( 
SELECT 0 AS Row, RTRIM(ISNULL(smv.definition, ssmv.definition)) AS CreateCmd 
FROM sys.all_objects AS v 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.sql_modules AS smv ON smv.object_id = v.object_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.system_sql_modules AS ssmv ON ssmv.object_id = v.object_id 
INNER JOIN (SELECT object_id, referenced_major_id FROM sys.sql_dependencies 
GROUP BY object_id, referenced_major_id) AS a ON v.object_id = a.referenced_major_id
WHERE (v.type = 'V' OR v.type = 'P' OR v.type = 'IF' OR v.type = 'TF' OR v.type =    'FN') 
AND SCHEMA_NAME(v.schema_id) = N'dbo' AND is_ms_shipped <> 1 
AND smv.execute_as_principal_id IS NULL AND ssmv.execute_as_principal_id IS NULL 
GROUP BY v.Name, smv.definition, ssmv.definition 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 AS Row, RTRIM(ISNULL(smv.definition, ssmv.definition)) AS CreateCmd 
FROM sys.all_objects AS v 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.sql_modules AS smv ON smv.object_id = v.object_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.system_sql_modules AS ssmv ON ssmv.object_id = v.object_id 
INNER JOIN (SELECT object_id, referenced_major_id FROM sys.sql_dependencies 
GROUP BY object_id, referenced_major_id) AS a ON v.object_id = a.object_id
WHERE (v.type = 'V' OR v.type = 'P' OR v.type = 'IF' OR v.type = 'TF' OR v.type = 'FN') 
AND SCHEMA_NAME(v.schema_id) = N'dbo' AND is_ms_shipped <> 1 
AND smv.execute_as_principal_id IS NULL AND ssmv.execute_as_principal_id IS NULL 
GROUP BY v.Name, smv.definition, ssmv.definition 
) S GROUP BY S.Row, CreateCmd 
) D GROUP BY CreateCmd ORDER BY Row
```